# Changing index in array / collection Laravel/Php

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i would like to change my array / collection index to its value.
I have something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkBad.png)

Is it possible in each array to change :
"date" : 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
to 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z : 100.00

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, it is. What methods have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `array_map` or the Collection's `map` method to achieve this.

Comment: are you trying to change the index or the date field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your original data is (array or Collection), but you can change it with `array_map` or `map`

```php
$array['ENFERMERIA'] = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        return [
            'send' => $item['send'],
            'open_date' => $item['open_date'],
            'name' => $item['name'],
            $item['date'] => $item['rate']
        ];
    },
    $array['ENFERMERIA']
);
```